# PayPal build errors

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, paypal

I keep getting these errors when i try to bluid my application

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPayment", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPaymentViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork", referenced from:
      -[ViewController Pay:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: yes this is Objective-C

Comment: I added the objective-c tag. My knowledge is pretty minimal, but hopefully the tag will attract more knowledgeable people.

Comment: on simulator the PayPal SDK **is not** working. you can compile it on real devices' architectures only like _armv6_, _armv7_, _armv7s_ or _arm64_. the architecture `i386` is not supported (that architecture used by the simulator).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this one: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/20

Let us know if that answer doesn't solve this for you.